# Tech stack for crop related information using satellte data

Tags: remote-sensing, agriculture, python

I want to perform tasks like crop area estimation, crop yield estimation, crop growth stage monitoring using Sentinel 2 or Landsat data for a particular region. What tech stack would I need to do that?

I looked at AcrGIS but it's not free, I couldn't figure out how to do it using QGIS. Ideally I want to get it done using Python. For python, I believe I would have to:

a) download the image,

b) use ML for the tasks mentioned above,

c) plot the results.

But what data do I use to train my models? How can I determine which type of crop it is? How can I show the results like type of crop and area of crop in the map? (I think I can use leaflet for that)?